# What is the correct syntax for the exclude and include options in org-publish?

Tags: org-export, org-publish

Does the `:exclude` and `:include` option of `org-publish-project-alist` allow multiple patterns?

Do they involve multiple `or` regexes or does each pattern require its own separate `:exclude` or `:include` line?

In my `init.el` temporary backup files are set as ``` (setq backup-directory-alist ``(("." . ".backups"))) ``` and although I have added `:exclude ".backups/*"` to org-publish-project-alist the `.backups` folders are also exported.

I am currently staging the exports to my local file system before sending them to the hosting server with `rsync` so I can exclude the `.backups` directories, but they shouldn't be exported.

Comment: The pattern should be a regexp.